# Can I put conditions in the MatchPattern portion of FindMatchingFiles in Team Build?

Tags: workflow, tfsbuild, workflow-activity

I'm trying to copy deployment batch files depending on the build configuration (e.g. Dev, QA, preprod, etc). I was using a switch statement, but that meant having to copy the same logic (sequence) for each case switch.
Is there a way to put the condition statement in my FindMatchingFiles activity? Perhaps in the MatchPattern argument?

Comment: No, not in built in activity, I belive MatchingFiles did support wildcards matching. If you use custom activity then of course you can have entire query language supported if your up to creating such an activity. If you say that your logic repeats perhaps you can introduce variables for parts that depend on switch - that way you can move most logic outside the switch and only assign variables there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to have my deployment batch files include the name of the configuration they apply to.

```
String.Format("{0}\_DeploymentScripts\{1}*.bat", SourcesDirectory, platform.Configuration)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to put logic in that activity.  You need to wrap the logic around it.  It is possible that you could simply have a switch statement that wraps the logic for building up the string for the match pattern and then use that value in the sequence that does the work.  That way you wouldn't need to repeat the sequence.